# clarification on behaviour of merge

Tags: java, database, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

Suppose I have an object A with id 1 on my persistence layer (i.e. on the DB)

If I do the following

```
A a = new A();
a.setId(1);
a.setSomeField("a value");
A managed_a = entityManager.merge(a);
```

would the entity manager retrieve the persisted entity with id 1 on the DB,
make it managed, and update it accordingly ?

Or the object with id 1 has to exsist in the persistence context in order in order for the above to happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The semantics of the merge operation applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing managed entity instance X' of the same identity or a new managed copy X' of X is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is    created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'.

On the first point: If your entity A with an id of 1 is already existing in your database table, then that means entity A is a **DETACHED** entity. In that case, fields of entity A will be merged to the data in your table, thus you'll see this as an UPDATE operation.

On the second point: If your entity A with an id of 1 is not existing in your database table, then entity A is considered as **NEW** entity. Thus, this will be an INSERT operation.

Both scenarios lead to a managed entity returned from a merge operation.